# To prove the "symmetry" of the solution to equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

$x$ and $y$ are real numbers (edited: thanks to @mcd's answer, now the "positive" requirement is removed) constrained by $ax+by=c$ where $a,b,c$ are strictly positive number.Given a strictly increasing, positive and continuous function $f(\cdot)$, if there exists solution(s) to $a\cdot f(x)+b\cdot f(y)=z$ where $z$ is a strictly positive number, prove that one of these solutions features that $x\geq y$.

A more direct way to see this is to use the graphs. The solutions to the equations are intersection points between lines $ax+by=c$ and $a\cdot f(x)+b\cdot f(y)=z$ (please see the following graphs). There are always intersection points falling in the bottom right half of the figure (that is, $x\geq y$).

I don't know how to prove this and I don't even know whether the claim above is right. But it seems intuitive when $a=b$ because in this case, if $x<y$ we can just exchange the values of $x$ and $y$ and we have $x\geq y$ and $x,y$ is a solution to the equations (see fig 1). But generally, when $a\neq b$, we cannot do this "exchange of values" because it may possible violate the constraint. But there may exist other transformations of values that "reflect" the point on one side of the diagonal to the other side. (see fig 2)

[image: fig 1][image: fig2]

The "symmetry" I mentioned in the title means that if there exists solution features $x<y$, then there exists solution with $x\geq y$. How to prove it?

Comment: 'features $x \le y$ and 'features $x>y$ do not make sense to me.

Comment: there could be multiple solutions, I want to prove that "if there is solution with $x<y$, then there should be another solution with $x\geq y$". This is trivial when $a=b$, I don't know if it can be generalized to $a\neq b$.

Comment: Here is a reformulation that may be helpful. First, let $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ be points on the graph of $y=f(x)$. Next, let $$p=\frac{a}{a+b},~ q=\frac{b}{a+b}=1-q, ~\bar{x}=\frac{c}{a+b}, ~\bar{y}=\frac{z}{a+b}.$$ Then the problem amounts to a geometry problem: Given a point $C=(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, can we find points $A=(x_1,y_1),B=(x_2,y_2)$ on the graph $y=f(x)$ such that $C=pA+(1-p)B$?

Comment: I am afraid that this is nothing to do with my question. In my question it is the weighed sum of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ that matters (both $x$ and $y$ are independent variables).

Comment: Isn't $f(x)=x$ and $z=2c$ a counterexample to the claim?

Comment: In this case, there is indeed no any solution at all. In my question, the prerequisite is that "if there is any solution", so this case is completely excluded.

Comment: If you want a helpful answer, then I think you need to rewrite the question: your first paragraph says "prove there exists a solution". Do you mean "assume there exists a solution"?

Comment: In fact, is your question: "Given that there is a solution to $ax+by=c$ and $af(x)+bf(y)=z$, with $a,b,c,x,y,z$ all positive, show that there is one with $x \ge y$"?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @mcd, $f(x)=x$ isn't a positive function, is it.

Comment: It is for x>0, which is all that matters here. You could replace by $f(x)=x+1 (x\ge0)$ and $f(x) = e^x (x<0)$ (and $z=2c+a+b$), if you liked. But the point is that the question didn't make sense as it was written - it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim isn't true. Let $f(x)=x^2$, $a=2$, $b=1$ $c=24$ and $z=342$. Then the equations are $2x+y=24$, $2x^2+y^2=342$, which reduces by substitution to $x^2-8x+39=0$ so $x=3, y=18$ and $x=13, y=-2$. So there is a solution with $y>x$ but none with $x>y$, because of the condition that $x, y >0$.

The original proposer's intuition fails, I think, because he has neglected the possibility that 'reflection' might take the solution outside the constrained domain.

Of course $x^2$ is only increasing for $x>0$, which is all that's relevant here. You can construct a similar counterexample with $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=e^x$ for $x<0$ if you care about this (you have to change 342 to 393 for the numbers to stay nice).

If you don't care about the positivity constraint, you could use $f(x)= 1 +\frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1} x$, with $a=2, b=1, c=\frac{1}{3}$, and $z=3$. Then the sole solution is one where $6x^3-x^2+1=0$, which only has a root where $x=-\frac{1}{2}, y=\frac{4}{3}$, so $y>x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the point here. But what if I remove the requirement that $x$ and $y$ are both positive? It seems holds if this requirement is removed.

Comment: @Perry_W It still doesn't.

Comment: I just cannot see an essential difference between the cases when $a=b$ and $a\neq b$, especially when $x,y$ are not restricted to be positive.

Comment: In the case $a=b$ the equations are both symmetric under the exchange of $x$ and $y$; when $a$ and $b$ are not equal, then there is no such symmetry. Think of the graphs. The transformation which maps $ax+by=c$ to itself is reflection in any line perpendicular to it. There is no reason why af(x)+bf(y) = z should map to itself under this reflection.

Comment: I understand that when $a\neq b$, a simple exchange of values does not work. But there could be other transformation of values to accomplish that. I have considered the graphs and put them in the question description. Basically, the solutions are the intersection points between the lines $ax+by=c$ and $af(x)+bf(y)=z$. Fig 1 is $a=b$ and Fig 2 is $a>b$. Both lines become "steeper" when $a$ increases, which makes it possible to find the other intersection point in the other side of diagonal. These two intersection points need not be a reflection to each other.

Comment: Yes., but the assertions you make are contradicted by the new counterexample I gave in the last paragraph of my answer. The graph of af(x)+bf(y)=z need not have the approximate shape you show in your example graphs: try plotting $2x+y=\frac{1}{3}$ and $2(1+\frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}x)+(1+\frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}y)=3$ or look at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/codxy39jdp

Comment: I see. Your example is very heuristic. Thanks so much for your help.